Combine two axes in a single figure
I have two axes that were created separately in a figure and I would like to combine them into a single figure as a subplot. Specifically, I have a function create_plot(*args)that returns axis objects, and I want to call this function twice to generate two different axes (ax1 and ax2). Afterward, I want to combine these two axes into a subplot layout and return a figure. Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:
def combine_subplots(ax1, ax2):
    # Combine the axes into a single figure (2x1 layout)
    ...
    return fig

# Create the axes using the function
ax1 = create_plot(*args1)
ax2 = create_plot(*args2)

# Combine the axes into a single figure
fig = combine_subplots(ax1, ax2)
fig.show()

How can I accomplish this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Read more than the top answer on the linked duplicate. Matplotlib's behaviour changed over time. Your simplest option is still passing pre-existing axes around.
